# Ice maker control arm front slot location?

Tags: repair, ice-maker

Bottom freezer ice maker control is not attached in the front. Experienced repairman knows where the slot is for reattaching. For those that do not have that experience he suggests removing the entire ice maker. Not going to happen here.

How far from the top is the whole? How far from the right is the hole?

[image: Control arm is shown with front attached]

[Amana Refrigerator Repair - The Ice Maker Arm Is Not Attached - ARB2257CW Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p80s8fmPPUs)

Comment: The bottom of the arm will be horizontal and it will be parallel to the ice maker.  So you can go by the rear hole.  However, just get a pocket mirror and use it to look behind the edge of the front housing to spot the hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Location can be located via a photo. Well placed quality image can be handle by taking a selfie with a phone so that location in image, focus and lighting can be easily improved. Then the additional info like the fact that the hole is actually a slot will allow for moving the wire into the correct rotation along with the point of contact identified by relation to angled indent and protruding circle. With this knowledge and confidence in the positioning force can be tried and found to be needed.

[image: Position in relation to indent and that it is a slot within the circle.]

[fixer1234](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/28390/fixer1234) hand mirror suggestion provoked the solution. A mirror in such close quarters with bifocals is problematic.